# Why cant i parse this pdf using pdfminer?

Tags: parsing, pdf, pdfminer

I wrote code that sucessfully parses thousands of different kind of pdfs.

However with this pdf, i get an error. Here is a very simple test code sample, that reproduces the error. My original code is too long to share here

```
file = open('C:/Users/username/file.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=LAParams())
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(file)
for page in pages:
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
```

https://filetransfer.io/data-package/dWnZbcWl#link

Here is the full error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15652/28568702.py in <module>
      7 for page in pages:
----> 8     interpreter.process_page(page)
      9     layout = device.get_result()

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in process_page(self, page)
    839             ctm = (1, 0, 0, 1, -x0, -y0)
    840         self.device.begin_page(page, ctm)
--> 841         self.render_contents(page.resources, page.contents, ctm=ctm)
    842         self.device.end_page(page)
    843         return

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in render_contents(self, resources, streams, ctm)
    852         self.init_resources(resources)
    853         self.init_state(ctm)
--> 854         self.execute(list_value(streams))
    855         return
    856 

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in execute(self, streams)
    857     def execute(self, streams):
    858         try:
--> 859             parser = PDFContentParser(streams)
    860         except PSEOF:
    861             # empty page

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in __init__(self, streams)
    219         self.streams = streams
    220         self.istream = 0
--> 221         PSStackParser.__init__(self, None)
    222         return
    223 

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\psparser.py in __init__(self, fp)
    513 
    514     def __init__(self, fp):
--> 515         PSBaseParser.__init__(self, fp)
    516         self.reset()
    517         return

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\psparser.py in __init__(self, fp)
    167     def __init__(self, fp):
    168         self.fp = fp
--> 169         self.seek(0)
    170         return
    171 

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in seek(self, pos)
    233 
    234     def seek(self, pos):
--> 235         self.fillfp()
    236         PSStackParser.seek(self, pos)
    237         return

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py in fillfp(self)
    229             else:
    230                 raise PSEOF('Unexpected EOF, file truncated?')
--> 231             self.fp = BytesIO(strm.get_data())
    232         return
    233 

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdftypes.py in get_data(self)
    290     def get_data(self):
    291         if self.data is None:
--> 292             self.decode()
    293         return self.data
    294 

C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdftypes.py in decode(self)
    271                 raise PDFNotImplementedError('Unsupported filter: %r' % f)
    272             # apply predictors
--> 273             if 'Predictor' in params:
    274                 pred = int_value(params['Predictor'])
    275                 if pred == 1:

TypeError: argument of type 'PDFObjRef' is not iterable
```

Can somebody try to load this into memory and if successful tell me how they did it?

Package versions used

```
conda                     4.11.0           py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.28.0           py39h832f523_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.4.4              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
pdfminer                  20191125           pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
pillow                    8.3.2            py39h916092e_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pytesseract               0.3.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.9.7           h7840368_3_cpython    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
```

I checked for problems with metadata but that is fine. I checked for encryption but that is also not the problem. Multipage is also no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I change

```py
if 'Predictor' in params:
```

to:

```py
if isinstance(params, dict) and 'Predictor' in params:
```

in file `pdftypes.py` (line 273), I don't get the error any more.

See: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/pull/471

The fix from PR 471, is not included in version `20191125`.

Comment: I updated pdfminer but that did not resolve the issue. Thanks for the replacement though, that fiexed it!

Comment: Yeah, the most recent version of pdfminer doe not inlcude the fix. You're welcome, of course.